# How can I make aws s3 upload accessible only with a predefined key as param?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way i can restrict upload to make it available only for requests including a certain predefined access key or something like that?

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "???",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*",
            "Key???": "some_constant_key???"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your policy only allows download, not any uploads. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: Look at using Presigned functionality for S3. That way, you can control when an upload is allowed.